# How to get sample data for null values for all columns in one table

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to find only 4 rows from my collection r_emp just for sample data by using my code  when i try to fetch it, it gives me error

> ORA-22165: given index [32768] must be in the range of [1] to [32767]

if i use r_emp.count in my loop and it gives buffer overflow because values are too large

```
DECLARE
  r_emp   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  t_emp   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('CUST_ID');
  v_array SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
    'CUST_TYPE',
    'CERT_TYPE_NAME',
    'CERT_NBR',
    'NEW_PARENT_CUST_ID'
  );
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  FOR i IN 1..v_array.COUNT LOOP
    FOR j IN 1..t_emp.COUNT LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'SELECT '||t_emp(j)||'  FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE where '||v_array(i)||' is null'
        BULK COLLECT INTO r_emp;
      FOR k IN 1..4 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i) || ': ' || r_emp(k));
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error report:

```
ORA-22165: given index [32768] must be in the range of [1] to [32767]
ORA-06512: at line 14
22165. 00000 -  "given index [%s] must be in the range of [%s] to [%s]"
*Cause:    Given index is not in the required range.
*Action:   Ensure that the given index is in the required range.
```

Comment: SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST Is a VARRAY of size 32767. You will need to use a different TYPE to hold more records.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason says in the comments SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST has a limit of 32767 your bulk collect into is retrieving more that 32767 rows.

One way of getting around this is just limit the bulk collect on rownum (means that your sample of four records is only being selected from the first 32760 records in the table not the full data set but you are just selecting the first 4 records it comes across not random ones so I can't see any issues with this. See code sample below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'SELECT '||t_emp(j)||'  FROM CUSTOMER_PROFILE where '||v_array(i)||' is null' AND rownum < 32760
        BULK COLLECT INTO r_emp;
```